# orderBy with multiple nested ng-repeats and ng-ifs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ng-if

http://plnkr.co/edit/cfQDcdHJGyGxWVHm9h3F

This is the plnkr.

I have been beating my head against this wall since noon, and I'm done messing with it. I am trying to orderBy 'thing' which is an int, so there should be no issues. There have been a lot of mentions of orderBy not working with hashes and other property values, and I've tried a number of solutions.

However, as you can see in the plnkr (after several hours of researching and trying other solutions) the moment I pasted it into plnkr the order is displaying properly, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. /facepalm

**When I go to load it onto our local host this is what I see:**

export

2

3

4

file

5

load

1

Yes, I've cleared my cache. The reason it is set up this way is because, if there is more than 1 object per thingType, I need a drop down menu, if there is only one, I don't want a drop down menu. **I am using VisualStudio. Does anyone know why this ordering is messed up when I try to run on a local host?**

```
        <ul>
         //loop over array of objects
          <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in content.types ">
            //if this object has more than 1 object in it
            <div ng-if="val.length === 1">
              //content goes inside list element
              <div ng-repeat="item in val">
                <h3>{{key}}</h3>
                <p>{{item.thing}}</p>
                <p>{{item.thingType}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

          //otherwise make multiple nested list elements
            <div ng-if="val.length > 1">
              <h3>{{key}}</h3>

              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in val">

                  <p>{{item.thing}}</p>
                  <p>{{item.thingType}}</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: can you provide the json please?

Comment: You probably have variation of an Angular version. If you changed your version in the plunker from v1.4.2 to, say, v1.3.15, the ordering would be as you get it via your Visual Studio project - see [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/U4msq2oKDLLIpCU7jwiR?p=preview). Angular has made some change with ordering of a hash. But for proper ordering or the use of `orderBy`, you should use arrays

Comment: I see. Thanks. 

The thing is, angular is not letting me dereference the array I'm looping over in the first ng-repeat properly. 'content.types[key]' is the same as 'val', I would have thought, orderBy: ' content.types[key][val].thing 'would have given me the property I want to order by, and that's where I ran into issues with dereferencing and trying to build a custom filter that will filter by that property. But I don't know of any other way to return that value for the orderBy